# Show column names of the table in 1st data row of the query output dynamically in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

There is one table , let us say **VW_RESULT** like below :

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>        <kbd>**`Quarter`**</kbd>   <kbd>**`Risk`**</kbd>          
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q0`</kbd>        <kbd>`2`</kbd>             
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q1`</kbd>        <kbd>`3`</kbd>             
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q2`</kbd>        <kbd>`1`</kbd>             
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q3`</kbd>        <kbd>`1`</kbd>             
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q4`</kbd>        <kbd>`2`</kbd>

Now I have to show the column names in the 1st row.

I want output like this :

<kbd>**`Col1`**</kbd>      <kbd>**`Col2`**</kbd>      <kbd>**`Col3`**</kbd>          
<kbd>`ID`</kbd>        <kbd>`Quarter`</kbd>   <kbd>`Risk`</kbd>          
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q0`</kbd>        <kbd>`2`</kbd>             
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q1`</kbd>        <kbd>`3`</kbd>             
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q2`</kbd>        <kbd>`1`</kbd>             
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q3`</kbd>        <kbd>`1`</kbd>             
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q4`</kbd>        <kbd>`2`</kbd>

I can easily achieve this if the number of columns is fixed, using `UNION ALL`.

> **But the number of columns will vary from time to time.**
>
> **I want to make this dynamic so that I don't have to put column names manually.**

I am using **Oracle 11g**.

Comment: The query must have a defined number of columns. what do you mean by the number of columns can vary? Are you using a dynamic query?

Comment: The table will change, new columns will be added in each month.

Comment: So when new column will be added, You will add that new column into your query or you are using `SELECT *`?

Comment: Is this the same problem as this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62075896/pl-sql-procedure-function-to-show-data-from-different-tables-dynamically-alongwi

Comment: @Tejash yes, I am doing `select  *`

Comment: @VBoka , yes that was the main problem.

Comment: I think you must go with the dynamic query then. prepare comma-separated list of the table's column using `user_tab_column` and union it with the actual query. execute it with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

Comment: So, have you then tried to create a procedure/function that wil do this ? Where is your effort ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, all your datatype should be string as all the columns are strings. In case if any of your datatype is other than string it will not work. Eg: ID column seems to be integer datatype, if you are trying to merge 'ID' string into ID column, according to SQL standard, it will fail. However below is the solution if all the columns in the respective table is in string format.

```
declare 

v_Sql1 varchar(1000);
v_Sql2 varchar(1000);

begin

select  (LISTAGG(chr(39)||column_name||chr(39), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 
column_id)) into v_Sql1 from cols where table_name = 'VW_RESULT'; 

v_Sql2:= 'select * from
(select  column_name from cols where table_name = ''VW_RESULT'') 
pivot
(
max(column_name)
for column_name in (' || v_Sql1 || '))
union select * from VW_RESULT'; 

dbms_output.put_line(v_Sql1);
dbms_output.put_line(v_Sql2);

execute immediate v_Sql2;

end;
/
```

Comment: SQL doesn't have string Datatype, please amend the solution as appropriate.

Comment: String is technical word defines Varchar, Varchar2, Char. In order to defile all the datatypes, technically mentioned as String

Answer (score 0):

Take your columns in variable and concatenate all columns you are getting at every run..execute your with execute immediate and concatenate your variable with the statement as well